# How do I iterate over a list containing dictionaries and check the values of the key in each of the dictionaries in Python?

Tags: python

So I want to be able to iterate over a list containing an amount of dictionaries and in each iteration check the values of certain keys in the dictionary. So lets say I have this list:

```
[{'x': 100, 'y': 305, 'name': 'David'}, {'x': 100, 'y': 302, 'name': 'Lukas'}]
```

Parameters for the functions would be `(placeholder,x,y)` where `placeholder` is the list coming from another function.

Now I want to go through each dictionary in the list and check if the value of key `'x'` is equal to the parameter `x` when calling the function, and if the value of key `'y'` is equal to the parameter `y` when calling the function.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
for item in mylist:
    if item['x'] == something:
        print 'Yay!'
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
my_list = [{'x': 100, 'y': 305, 'name': 'David'}, {'x': 100, 'y': 302, 'name': 'Lukas'}]

def my_func(placeholder, x, y):
    return [dct["x"] == x and dct["y"] == y for dct in placeholder]

print(my_func(my_list, x=100, y=305))
```

Output:

`[True, False]`

Answer (score 0):

If you want little more verbosity:

```
def func(placeholder, x, y):
    for index, item in enumerate(placeholder):
        print "For Index:",index
        if item['x'] == x:
            print "X is equal"
        else:
            print "X not equal"
        if item['y'] == y:
            print "Y is equal"
        else:
            print "Y not equal"
```